# How to get word from string containing numbers through sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I have string "word123" need to extract only "word" using sscanf.

```
          char str[10];
          sscanf("word1233","%s", str);
```

Comment: You're better off doing it character-by-character with a proper parser ... but ... `sscanf("word123", "%[^0123456789]", str);` should do it ... https://ideone.com/76L81O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the requirements, I don't think this is the best way to do it, but if you want to do it this way, I would simply accept a string that ignores digits.

```
sscanf("word1233","%[^0123456789]", str);
```

You could also specify only the allowed characters:

```
sscanf("word1233","%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]", str);
```

Note that that would only allow lower case letters.

Here is a method that might make more sense in many situations:

```
char str[10] = {0};
    
char *s = "word1234";
    
for(int i=0; s[i] && isalpha(s[i]); i++)
    str[i] = s[i];
```

Do note that this is dangerous if `str` is not big enough, but on the other hand, that goes for your method too. You could correct that with:

```
sscanf("word1233","%9[^0123456789]", str);
```

A similar thing needs to be done for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%[^...]` to match only characters not in the brackets. Then you can list the digit characters there.

```
char str[10];
sscanf("word1233", "%[^0123456789]", str);
```